# Ubuntu 16.04.4 startup issues in UEFI mode

Tags: partitioning, startup, bluefish

translation made by google translator

I have an Acer Travel Mate P notebook that came from the factory with windows 10 pro. I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.4 in UEFI mode - without doalboot. The system completes the installation normally, but when I restart the computer the system does not detect any system and Ubuntu does not start.
Is there a possible solution to the problem? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try going into the Setup (BIOS) and reset settings to the `factory default` and the `save` and `exit`.

Comment: Did not work.
continues to display a "No Bootable Device" message.

Comment: Just install Ubuntu again.  Be sure to select the button to install it on your hard disk; not to merely "try Ubuntu" for the purpose of evaluation.